# Assigning dataframe id based on id in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes called dataframe A and dataframe B

```
             A
    id| column1 |column2
    3 |    439  |  2398
    41|    498  |   34
    2 |    233  |   43

           B
    column1 |column2
      439   |  2398
      498   |   56
      233   |   43
```

I would like to assign an id column to dataframe B based on the ids in dataframe A. If a row is present in dataframe A and in dataframe B, I would like to assign the corresponding id from dataframe A to dataframe B. If a row in dataframe B is not in dataframe A I would like to assign "None" to that cell in the id column in B. That is, I would like to have

```
             B
    id  | column1 |column2
    3   |    439  |  2398
    None|    498  |   56
    2   |    233  |   43
```

**Question:** How do I assign the ids from dataframe A to dataframe B based on the columns in dataframe B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a left merge. Note for a numeric series `NaN` values will force `id` series to become of type `float`. In most situations this isn't a problem, and I wouldn't advise you to "force" type conversion row-by-row.

```
res = pd.merge(B, A, how='left')

print(res)

   column1  column2   id
0      439     2398  3.0
1      498       56  NaN
2      233       43  2.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does this work as well if dataframe B already has an id column with a NaN value? Does this overwrite that id to an id from dataframe A?

Comment: @titusAdam, No. That would be [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). The solution assumes, as per your inputs, that `B` only has columns `['column1', 'column2']`.